# [ROS2] Bt_navigator Node not recognized

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I recently decided to use the bt proposed by Nav2 from Humble, Navigate To Pose With Consistent Replanning And If Path Becomes Invalid.

When I start the bt the following error pops up.

```
[bt_navigator-1] [ERROR] [bt_navigator]: Exception when loading BT: Error at line 13: -> Node not recognized: PathExpiringTimer 
[bt_navigator-1] [ERROR] [bt_navigator]: Error loading XML file: config_nav2/bt_navigator.xml
```

This log regards PathExpirinTimer node but I obtain the same error aso for "GlobalUpdatedGoal" and "IsPathValid".

I suspect something related with  `nav2_tree_nodes.xml` but cannot manage the error.

I currently have installed release 1.1.5 from DEB, which should be the last one.
I am usgin ROS2 humble and ubuntu 22.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/412095/%5Bros2%5D-bt_navigator-node-not-recognized/) by [Mrmara](https://answers.ros.org/users/40719/mrmara/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2023-02-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2023-02-01**:
You didn't provide your error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes my bad, I am going to correct the question. Anyway I realized the problem. Just forgot to add inside bt_navigator params plugin_lib_names those specific nodes.
Thanks for answearing

---

Originally posted by [Mrmara](https://answers.ros.org/users/40719/mrmara/) with karma: 71 on 2023-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0